# mdDialog select item by id

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material, mddialog

I'm trying to get the width of a div inside a mdDialog, but the controller for that dialog is executed before the HTML loads, so the selector doesn't find anything. Is there a way to use the `window.onload()` or the `document.ready()` functions for that dialog?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the element using a timeout, so the function will execute after the html render. Inject $timeout in the dialog controller and then measure the div from inside the timed out function:

$timeout(function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('yourDivId');
});

Comment: Whew, thank you so much. This saved me a ton of time.